# Dynamic Add attribute in <form> angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I am trying to add Dynamic add attribute in  using angularJs Directive
I want to add html tag in form dynamically

My view :

```
<div ng-show="edit_tasks">   
   <edittask-form><edittask-form> 
</div>
```

My Form Html

```
{
<div>
  <form ng-submit="submitFrom()" csrf-tokenized>
    Task Name<input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="newtask.name" required />
    Task Description<input type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="newtask.description" required />
    Start Date <input type="text" placeholder="Start date" ng-model="newtask.start_date" required />
    Start Date <input type="text" placeholder="End date" ng-model="newtask.end_date" required />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
}
```

My Directives

```
module.directive("edittaskForm", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "<%=asset_path 'tasks/task_form.html' %>",
    controller: tasksCtrl,
    replace: false,
    link: function(scope, elt, attrs, controller) {
          scope.form = elt.find("form");
          console.log(scope.form);

          scope.taskEdit = function(task) {
            scope.task =  task;
            scope.show_tasks = false;
            scope.edit_tasks = true;
            scope.newtask = task;
          };
        }
  }
});
```

How Can I add `<input type="text" name="xyz" />`
in form

Thk's in Advance

Comment: It is not clear that you mean by this. Where do you want to put this input? Why can it not be placed straight in the html? Are you referring to the fact that the name attribute on inputs cannot be set dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in the template simply by using ngShow but if you want to do it in your directive i guess you cant do that in link function because it does not support html transforms as i know, i guess you should try to do it in compile function, you can read more about it [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0):

If you want add dynamic attribute to form element in angularjs, you can do following thing.

**step 1:**
Create custom directive which reads form element(s) as below:

> Note: Here I am taking all input elements with **querySelectorAll('selector')**, if you want take single you can take **querySelector('selector')**.

```
app.directive('dynamicAttribute', function ($compile) {
    return {
             link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                  var allElements=element[0].querySelectorAll('input');
                  for(var i=0;i<allElemts.length;i++){
                      allElements[i].setAttribute('ng-keypress','resetValues($event)');
                 }
                     $compile(allElements)(scope);
              }
         };
       });
```

**Step 2:** Add this directive to your  element

```
 <form name="userForm" dynamic-attrubute>
    <input type="text"   name='name' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="name">
    <input type="text"  name='password' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="password">
</form>
```

*Dynamically keypress attribute is added with value function*
[image]